# RubyMonk, Palindrome

Tags: ruby, palindrome

Learning Ruby, currently doing the palindrome method creator on Ruby Monk.

Basically, write a method that returns true if a string is indeed a palindrome.

This is my code.

```
def palindrome?(sentence)

sentence.downcase!


array_1 = sentence.split("")

array_2 = sentence.reverse.split("")

if array_1 == array_2
    true
else
    false
end
end

p palindrome?("NeverOddOrEven")
```

It works, but only if there are no spaces between each word.

So if you check "Never Odd Or Even" (as opposed to "NeverOddOrEven") it fails.

How should I fix this?

Thanks!

Comment: I think your input should contain a space too `p palindrome?("Never Odd Or Even")`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add:

```
sentence.gsub!/\W/, ''
```

just after `sentence.downcase!`

Also note, that your method has a side effect:

```
string = 'NeverOddOrEven'
p palindrome?(string)   #=> true
p string                #=> neveroddoreven
```

To fix this, change first two lines to:

```
sentence = sentence.downcase.gsub /\W/, ''
```

Comment: Worked! Thanks a mil. I assume that \W is whitespace and that substitutes whitespace for no-whitespace? (i realise thats worded poorly)

Comment: `\W` is the opposite of `\w`, which is `[a-zA-Z0-9_]`. Instead of assuming, get in the habit of reading the Regexp documentation. Assuming will lead to bugs.

Comment: @user2085143 - One more point, you don't need to use an array, String has its own reverse method. :)